# Product is not adding into cart when fetched into product page with ajax in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I am showing one category product in a popup when out of four options is chosen in product page. For that i have made a product collection page in root of magento and loading the product out of some bunch of them according to data sent through jquery ajax. Everything is working as well.

But product in popup is not adding to cart.

Code for the category page in root of magento :

```
<?php
error_reporting();
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(0);
if (isset($_GET['lens_value'])) {
$lens_value = $_GET['lens_value'];
?>

<div style="float: right;
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
top: 80px;
width: 89%;
height: 600px;
display:block;
z-index: 9991;
background-color: white;" id="cross-div">
<img src="http://domain.com/skin/frontend/package/theme/images/x-mark.png" style="width: 40px;
height: 40px;
float: right;">
     <h1 style="
margin-left: 7%;
font-size: 29px;
font-weight: 600;">   Select Your lens</h1>
<h2 style="
margin-left: 7%;">Enter or upload your power post checkout
</h2>

</div>
<?php

$categoryIds = array(
    56
); //category id

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array(
    'in' => $categoryIds
));
if ($lens_value == '2') {
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('lens_code', '55');
} elseif ($lens_value == '3') {
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('lens_code', '53');
} elseif ($lens_value == '4') {
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('lens_code', '54');
}
//$collection->addFieldToFilter('lens_code','55');       

?>
<?php
$_collectionSize = $collection->count();
//echo "collection size".$_collectionSize;
?>
<?php //$_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); 
?>

<div style="width: 100%;
height: auto;
z-index: 9992;display:block;" id="in-popup-div">

    <ul class="products-grid" style="position: relative;
z-index: 9993;
margin-left: 7%;" >

<?php
$i = 0;
foreach ($collection as $product):
//$product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($_product->getId());

//$attVal = $product->getOptions();

//$optStr = "";

//var_dump($product);
?>



    <li class="item<?php
        if (($i - 1) % $_columnCount == 0):
?> first<?php
        elseif ($i % $_columnCount == 0):
?> last<?php
        endif;
?>" style="display:inline-block;width:30%; border: 1px solid #ccc">
                <a href="<?php
        echo $product->getProductUrl();
?>" title="<?php
        echo $product->getName();
?>">
                        <img src="<?php
        echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(197, 167);
?>" style="width:100%;height:100px;" alt="<?php
        echo $product->getName();
?>" border="0" />
                    </a>
                <h2 class="product-name" style="text-align:left;margin-left:30px"><a style="color:black" href="<?php
        echo $product->getProductUrl();
?>" title="<?php
        echo $product->getName();
?>"><?php
        echo $product->getName();
?></a></h2>
                <h2 class="product-name" style="text-align:left;margin-left:30px"><a style="color:black" href="<?php
        echo $product->getProductUrl();
?>" title="<?php
        echo $product->getName();
?>"><?php
        echo $product->getDescription();
?></a></h2>
               <div class="price-box" style="text-align:center;">
               <?php
        echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($product->getPrice(), true, false);
?>
               </div>
                <div class="actions" style="text-align:center">
                    <?php
        if ($product->isSaleable()):
?>

                    <?php
            $formkey = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();

?>

  <button class="button" style="width:100%" onclick="onclick="setLocation('<?php echo ('http://domain.com/index.php/checkout/cart/add/')?>uenc/aHR0cDovL2NkLm15Y29kZXJpZGUuY29tL2luZGV4LnBocC9sZW5zLmh0bWw,/product/<?php echo $product->getId();?>/form_key/<?php echo $formkey ?>/')" title="<?php
            echo 'Add to Cart';
?>" type="submit"><span><span><?php
            echo 'Add to Cart';
?></span></span></button>
                    <?php
        else:
?>
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php
            echo 'Out of stock';
?></span></p>
                    <?php
        endif;
?>

                </div>
                <p style="text-align:center">Submit power post checkout</p>
            </li>

        <?php
    endforeach;
?> 
        </ul>
        </div> <?php
} else {
    echo "value is not negligible";
}
?>
```

Code includes html and css and that's why seems not good formatted.

Answer (score 0):

You better to use magento API for your add to cart button, change your add to cart button onclick action to that:

```
onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product); ?>')"
```

Comment: I have tried it but product is not adding to cart. Any other clue?

Comment: Try to change your button type from `type="submit"` to type `type="button"`.

Comment: i am thinking to make it a module. Can you guide me in this direction? Because i think it is not working with direct php page.